# moving a graph in another slide to fit in one page

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I need to move the graph in the third page slide in the second page and make everything fit.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,bg=cyan} %background color
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=blue} %colore titoli
%\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=yellow,bg=cyan} %colore e background in un comando

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 


\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{cobalt}{rgb}{0.0, 0.28, 0.67} 
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure,fg=cobalt} 


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} %rido

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cobalt} % all frames will have cobalt bullets

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm,text margin right=5mm} %margini

%\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo.jpeg}}
\title{\textbf{title }}
\author{name}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{
  \inst{1}%
  thesis\\
  uni
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  prof1\\
  pro2
}

\date[VLC 2013] % (optional)
{Lmarch}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.jpeg}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot, 
    xmin=-0.2, 
    xmax=0.8, 
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3,
    yticklabels={,,}, 
    xticklabels={,,},  
    ytick=\empty, 
    xtick=\empty, 
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none}
    ]
    
    \addplot[black,mark=.] table{capitoli/capitolo_02/data/dati_polinomio_Greitzer_esempio.txt};
    \coordinate (A) at (0,1.862);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0.212,2.275);
    \coordinate (D) at (0.212,1.862);
    
    \draw[<->] (-0.05,1.862) -- (-0.05,0);
    \draw[dashed] (B) -- (-0.01,0);
    \draw[<->] (C) -- (D);
    \draw[<->] (A) -- (D);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0.7,0);
    
    \node[text width=2cm] at (0.37,2.1) {2H};
    \node[text width=2cm] at (0.212,1.7) {2W};
    \node[text width=2cm] at (-0.05,0.9) {$\psi_{c0}$};
    \node[text width=2cm] at (0.55,1) {$\Psi_c$};
    
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\caption{\textit{Definizione dei parametri del polinomio cubico}}
  \label{fig:polinomio cubico}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
\Psi_c(m,N)=\psi_{c0}+H(N)\left[+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{W(N)}-1\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\phi}{W(N)}\right)^3\right]
\label{eq:polinomio cubico}
\nonumber
\end{equation}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=-0.1, 
    xmax=0.4, 
    ymin=1,
    ymax=2.8, 
    xlabel={$[kg/s]$}, 
    ylabel={Rapporto di compressione},
    width = \textwidth,
    height = 0.57\textwidth,
    %yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=5},
    xticklabel style={rotate=-90,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=2},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left},
    legend columns=-1
    ]
    
    \addplot[blue,mark=.,very thick] table{capitoli/capitolo_02/data/dati_polinomio_Greitzer_esempio.txt};
    \addplot[red,mark=.,very thick] table{capitoli/capitolo_02/data/fisico.txt};
    
    %\legend{$40000 rpm$,$45000 rpm$,$50000 rpm$,$55000 rpm$}   
    
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\caption{\textit{Scostamento del polinomio cubico}}
  \label{fig:spostamento_surge}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (i) your preamble is mess, you load some packages and libraries three time! Please clean up it. (ii) tables used in diagrams are unknown to us. (ii) how you like to have two pictures in the same frame? In the separate slides (visible with `uncover` or similar showing option) ?

Comment: I know it's a mess, but since I am doing copy and paste from my thesis it's the only way I know it'll work. I'd like the two images side bby side and under the equation: \begin{equation}
\Psi_c(m,N)=\psi_{c0}+H(N)\left[+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{\phi}{W(N)}-1\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\phi}{W(N)}\right)^3\right]
\label{eq:polinomio cubico}
\nonumber
\end{equation}

Comment: @Noob_Latex Zarko 's comment applies anyway. You should then delete the packages loaded multiple times in your thesis.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get, where should and use uncover?

Comment: I just ask you, what you like to have. If you like to have two images in parallel, visible at the same tima, than you not need any of possibilities how to show up one of images. Anyway, you can already clean up at least you preamble and remove all multiple loaded packages.

Comment: two images in parallel, visible at the same time